# program freeze using argparse and concurrent.futures package

Tags: python, multiprocessing, argparse

I was writing a python program to process the NGS sequencing data on the HPC bash termial. The program ran normally on jupyter notebook on my mac either using single process or multiple processes. However, as long as i tried to pass in the parameter in the terminal using the argpase package. The program won't give me the final result, instead it would ran indefinitly as if the process has not finished. I checked and was almost for sure it was caused by some conflict between the argpase and the concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor().So, could anyone give some suggestions as how to solve this problem?
Thank you!

The following code produce the freezing problem on the terminal.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd
import time
import concurrent.futures
import argparse


def run(args):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    input_file = args.input
    output_file = args.output
    chunk = args.chunk_size

    def cal_breaking(data):
        for index, row in data.iterrows():
            if row[1] == 0:  # mapping to the foward strand
                data.at[index, 'breaking_pos'] = int(row[5]) + int(row[3])
            elif row[1] == 16:  # mapping to the reverse strand
                data.at[index, 'breaking_pos'] = int(row[3])
            else:
                pass
        return data

    new_df = pd.DataFrame(
        columns=['QNAME', 'FLAG', 'RNAME', 'POS', 'MAPQ', 'CIGAR', 'RNEXT', 'PNEXT', 'TLEN', 'SEQ', 'QUAL'])
    processes = []
    for df in pd.read_csv(input_file, delimiter='\t', usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], chunksize=chunk):
        df.columns = ['QNAME', 'FLAG', 'RNAME', 'POS', 'MAPQ', 'CIGAR', 'RNEXT', 'PNEXT', 'TLEN', 'SEQ', 'QUAL']
        df = df.loc[~df['CIGAR'].str.contains('S') & ~df['CIGAR'].str.contains(
            'H')]  # filtered out those read that contains 'soft clip' and 'hard clip' sequences
        df['CIGAR'] = df.iloc[:, 5].str.extract(
            r'(\d+)')  # -d+ regex expression representing one or more numbers(0-9)
        df['breaking_pos'] = None
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            processes.append(executor.submit(cal_breaking, df))
    for process in processes:
        new_df = pd.concat([new_df, process.result()], sort=True)

    new_df['count'] = 1
    new_df = new_df.groupby(['RNAME', 'breaking_pos']).count()['count'].reset_index()
    new_df['end'] = new_df['breaking_pos'] + 1
    new_df = new_df[['RNAME', 'breaking_pos', 'end', 'count']]
    new_df.to_csv(output_file, '\t', index=None, header=None)
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'process finished in {round(end - start, 2)} second(s)')


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="tagging HiC-Pro pair's sub-compartment")
    parser.add_argument("-in", help="input pairs file", dest="input", type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-out", help="output files name", dest="output", type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-ck", help="read in chunk size", dest="chunk_size", type=int, required=True)
    parser.set_defaults(func=run)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    args.func(args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The following code ran well on the terminal without problem if I don't use multiprocessing:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd
import time
import argparse


def run(args):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    input_file = args.input
    output_file = args.output
    chunk = args.chunk_size

    def cal_breaking(data):
        for index, row in data.iterrows():
            if row[1] == 0:  # mapping to the foward strand
                data.at[index, 'breaking_pos'] = int(row[5]) + int(row[3])
            elif row[1] == 16:  # mapping to the reverse strand
                data.at[index, 'breaking_pos'] = int(row[3])
            else:
                pass
        return data

    new_df = pd.DataFrame(
        columns=['QNAME', 'FLAG', 'RNAME', 'POS', 'MAPQ', 'CIGAR', 'RNEXT', 'PNEXT', 'TLEN', 'SEQ', 'QUAL'])

    for df in pd.read_csv(input_file, delimiter='\t', usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], chunksize=chunk):
        df.columns = ['QNAME', 'FLAG', 'RNAME', 'POS', 'MAPQ', 'CIGAR', 'RNEXT', 'PNEXT', 'TLEN', 'SEQ', 'QUAL']
        df = df.loc[~df['CIGAR'].str.contains('S') & ~df['CIGAR'].str.contains(
            'H')]  # filtered out those read that contains 'soft clip' and 'hard clip' sequences
        df['CIGAR'] = df.iloc[:, 5].str.extract(
            r'(\d+)')  # -d+ regex expression representing one or more numbers(0-9)
        df['breaking_pos'] = None
        new_df = pd.concat([new_df, cal_breaking(df)], sort=True)

    new_df['count'] = 1
    new_df = new_df.groupby(['RNAME', 'breaking_pos']).count()['count'].reset_index()
    new_df['end'] = new_df['breaking_pos'] + 1
    new_df = new_df[['RNAME', 'breaking_pos', 'end', 'count']]
    new_df.to_csv(output_file, '\t', index=None, header=None)
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'process finished in {round(end - start, 2)} second(s)')


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="tagging HiC-Pro pair's sub-compartment")
    parser.add_argument("-in", help="input pairs file", dest="input", type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-out", help="output files name", dest="output", type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-ck", help="read in chunk size", dest="chunk_size", type=int, required=True)
    parser.set_defaults(func=run)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    args.func(args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If there's any question about the `argparse` performance, `print(args)` to check what it produces.  If you are happy with that `Namespace` you can focus on other parts of the program.

Answer (score 0):

> The ProcessPoolExecutor class is an Executor subclass that uses a pool of processes to execute calls asynchronously. ProcessPoolExecutor uses the multiprocessing module, which allows it to side-step the Global Interpreter Lock but also means that only picklable objects can be executed and returned.

According to the doc by default it will take *max_workers <= 61*, Here i modified some part to work.

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
            processes.append(executor.submit(cal_breaking, df))
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your method, but the problem still remains. Because the file contain 100000 line, and the chunksize I set is 50000, there are actually only two processes being submitted. But it just could not finish, and without any error message.